# Unable to display classic asp page on local machine on iis7

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, connection-string

I am new to classic asp deployment. I have deployed my classic asp project on my local machine on iis7 of windows7.

When I browse my website from iis it displays the home page but when i click on search button on page which should redirect to **search.asp** but the page is not displayed and no errors are shown.
It shows `The website cannot display the page`.

Sqlserver version: 2008

My connection string:

```
MM_mtyadi_STRING.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Integrated Security=True;"
```

My html code is :

```
<a href="html/search.asp"><img src="images/search.gif" width=351 height=51 border="0">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you assume it's related to your connection string? It seems to me it's about IIS config or wrong URL.

Comment: you have to configure iis to send asp script errors to the client (your browser) furthermore you have to check you internet explorer settings for "show friendliy http errors" this should not be checked.

Comment: Post some code, are u using Form Post?? or Response.Redirect?

Comment: <a href="html/search.asp"><img src="images/search.gif" width=351 height=51 border="0">

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS7 classic asp has its own error reporting settings. 
In IIS manager you have to double click ASP to get the properties page to pop up.

Expand: Debugging Properties:
Set send errors to browser to : TRUE

That will give you detailed classic asp errors where you can understand where your code is breaking.